# computer don't show and enable "sleep" option

Tags: windows-10

so suddenly my computer doesn't let me enter sleep mode - only shut down. it's really weird because also in the settings I can't find sleep mode, it's basicly disappeard from my computer.

Comment: Can you re-enable them by following [these instructions?](https://www.top-password.com/blog/fix-sleep-option-missing-in-windows-power-menu/). A quick way to open the power options is [`%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.PowerOptions /page  pageGlobalSettings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28603116/935614)

Comment: no, i did all the methoods i can and all seems to doesnt help. computer still cant sleep.